# Download an instagram video from URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, instagram

I have a bot which ive been wanting to add a feature where a user inputs an instagram link and it returns the downloaded media from the post. The issue is i have no idea how to get the video link to download it.

I've tried using the Instagram download packages from npm however they usually end up not returning anything. I've also tried fetching the web page however the page isn't static so requesting the HTML doesn't give me any useful data. Another option I've tried is to look through inspect element on the website to find anything useful that could help but after a while, I ended up not finding anything useful that i could access from code.

Any help or idea would be good as ive tried about anything i can think of.

Answer (score 0):

*Short answer:*

1. Have an instagram account without 2FA.
2. Install gallery-dl:

```
sudo apt update && sudo snap install gallery-dl
```

3. Download the resource:

```
gallery-dl -g -u "<username>" -p "<password>" "https://www.instagram.com/p/CUU9-FFFaE5/"
```

Write some Node.js code which will execute that command asyncronously like this or in other way:

```
const command = `gallery-dl -g -u "${user}" -p "${pass}" "${url}"`;
exec(command, async (err, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (err) {
        // getting the err.message
    } else {
        // use the downloaded file name/path to do your stuff
    }
});
```

*Personal thoughts:*

At first I will not recommend to do that in non official way, but apart from that, theoretically you can do it in 2 ways: getting the media with tool like [gallery-dl](https://github.com/mikf/gallery-dl) or some other alternative tool that you want to work with, or just parsing it for your own (I've worked on parsing it via Node.js snippet about 3 years ago, and in that moment Instagram have been changing their API policy or something like that, so i don't actually remember the way i did that).

Actually in some point both ways are the same, they're just grabbing the data, but anyway.. you can have some account on instagram only for doing that parsing **without** any multi-factor authentication, and use **gallery-dl**.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this could work?
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/reference/ig-media

You would have to use the Instagram Graph API for this.

Comment: from my understanding of how this api works i would need to set up an oauth system and let people log into my app using instagram and then fetch data using their access token but this is not how i want to solve my problem.

Comment: A link-only answer is not very helpful, especially considering links tend to change/break over time and remove all value for future viewers of your answer. It's best to include a synopsis of the link's contents that meets the criteria laid out in the OP's question.

Comment: @esqew thanks for the reminder, will look out for it.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you could try one of the products on rapidapi under the search for an 'instagram media downloader' and go from there?

I found this one that might be able to help you: https://rapidapi.com/arraybobo/api/instagram-media-downloader/

Comment: A link-only answer is not very helpful, especially considering links tend to change/break over time and remove all value for future viewers of your answer. It's best to include a synopsis of the link's contents that meets the criteria laid out in the OP's question.

Comment: They charge a monthly price for using there api unless you go below 100 calls.